# Add values to end of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays and I want to be able to add values to the array every time a user hits the add button.

```
var transactions = [];
transactions[0] = []; // holds date
transactions[1] = []; // holds transaction type
transactions[2] = []; // holds amount


transactions[0][i] = $("date").value;
transactions[1][i] = $("transType").value;
transactions[2][i] = parseFloat( $("amount").value);
```

these are the snippets . . . I realize I need to work on validation (which I will do) at this point I'm more concerned with loading the arrays.  The problem is the method I'm familiar with works with 1-dimensional arrays and I don't know how to replace it.

in short is it possible to reproduce this:

```
transactions[transactions.length] = $("date").value;
```

for a multidimensional array.

Thank You

Comment: disregard the [i] that was an attempt using a counter

Answer (score 1):

Use `push`:

```
transactions[0].push( $("date").value );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method. It allows you to push values on to the end of an array.

For your use case, you can do that on both levels of the array. See below:

```
var transactions = [];
transactions.push([]);
transactions.push([]);

transactions[0].push( $('date').value );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem for using the same approach:

```
transactions[0][transactions[0].length] = $("date").value;
```

or with `push` method:

```
transactions[0].push($("date").value);
```

... keeping in mind that you've initialized `transactions[0]` with empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just idem for multidimensional

```
transactions[0][transactions[0].length] = var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little weird you are doing:

```
[[array of transaction dates],[array of transaction types],[array of transaction amounts]]
```

Are you sure you don't want

```
[array of transactions, with date,type,amount properties]
```

?

```
var transactions = [];
transactions.push({'date': $("date").value, 'type': $("transType").value, 'amount': parseFloat( $("amount").value)});

var i = 0;

alert('date ' + transactions[i].date + ' type ' + transactions[i].type + ' amount ' + transactions[i].amount);
```